# Openshift import-image fails to pull because of certification errors, however docker does

Tags: docker, openshift-origin, docker-registry

i have created a TLS private docker registry. I have updated the ca-trust in the machine that I want to pull from and it works, curl works without the -k parameter, docker can pull etc. However, the openshift import-image command fails, due to signed by unknown authority error. Openshift secrets are mostly for username and passwords, I haven't found any example on the internet about importing certificates. I also have to mention that this registry works fine as an insecure registry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the private registries CA to the masters operating system CA root bundle (which is what openshift uses to check remote registries).

Comment: I have already done that, it works with curl and docker but not with openshift import-image